# ¿ Como importar datos de un archivo excel a asp.net core 2.1 mvc para luego almacenarlos en una base de datos sql server con lenguaje C#?

Tags: sql-server, excel, asp.net-core

Soy nuevo trabajando con asp.net core y los tutoriales que encuentro ya se para importar o exportar son para la version 2.0 la cual incluye web forms, pero apartir de la versión 2.1 ya no se incorporaron las web forms. De antemano gracias.

Comment: Por favor se mas especifico con tu pregunta.